# Why can't I use anyhow::Context together with try_into()?

Tags: rust

I'm doing this:

```
use anyhow::{Context, Result};

fn as_float(bytes: Vec<u8>) -> Result<f64> {
  let a : &[u8; 8] = bytes.clone()
    .try_into()
    .context(format!("There is no data"))?;
  Ok(f64::from_be_bytes(*a))
}
```

I'm getting:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Vec<u8>: std::error::Error` is not satisfied
   --> src/data.rs:76:14
    |
76  |             .context(format!("There is no data"))?;
    |              ^^^^^^^ the trait `std::error::Error` is not implemented for `Vec<u8>`
```

What's wrong and how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The error type for this conversion is the `Vec` itself](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#associatedtype.Error). The idea is that if the conversion was unsuccessful you can still use the original `Vec`. But this means it does not implement [`std::error::Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/error/trait.Error.html), which is required for `anyhow`.

Instead of `context()`, map the error and create an anyhow error:

```rust
.try_into().map_err(|_| anyhow::anyhow!("there is no data"))
```

Or use the slice conversion methods that return [`TryFromSliceError`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/array/struct.TryFromSliceError.html), which does implement `Error`:

```rust
bytes.as_slice()
    .try_into()
    .context(format!("There is no data"))?;
```

As an aside, not that the conversion will fail if there is more than one element, not just if there are zero.

Comment: `.as_slice` did the trick, thanks!